# How to read external file into a variable for post-build events in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, version-control, post-build-event

Is there a way to read the contents of an external file into a variable in a Visual Studio post-build event?

The reason I want to do this is that we're going to want a post-build event that every developer runs to copy a built assembly to a certain local UNC path, but each developer will likely have a different UNC path.  So we can't hardcode the path into the project file.  If we could read fro an external file we could then ignore that in source control and just rely on setting the path value in that file.

If reading in a file isn't possible is there any other way we could achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you can't read an external file into a variable in a VS post-build event.  However, you can run an external batch file and provide it with arguments.  This allows us to do per-developer post-build batch scripts by excluding such scripts from source control, then checking for their existence in the post-build event and executing them if they exist, like so:

```
CD "$(ProjectDir)"
IF EXIST postBuild.bat (
@ECHO Post-build script exists at: $(ProjectDir)postBuild.bat - executing...
CALL "$(ProjectDir)postBuild.bat" "$(TargetPath)" "$(TargetDir)"
)
```

Obviously the batch file and post-build can later be expanded to pass more arguments as and when they are needed.  The batch file `postBuild.bat` in the project dir then looks something like this:

```
@REM **********
@REM Post-build script; assumes params:
@REM postBuild.bat "$(TargetPath)" "$(TargetDir)"
@REM **********

@ECHO TargetPath: %1
@ECHO TargetDir: %2

[...]
```